# Can NFC tags be protected from being overwritten?

Tags: nfc

The Nexus S can write to NFC tags. How do you stop anyone with a Nexus S from overwriting your tag?

eg. If you have an NFC tag on a flyer that launches a video, can a guy with a Nexus S overwrite it and replace it with a link to his website?

Beginner here, just trying to get a handle on NFC, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, many tag types permit write protection, some globally, and other more sophisticated ones by memory section inside the tag.

When you get your tag detected in your Android NFC app, then you can get a Tag object and read and write to the tag, including protecting it from further writing.

This is all described in the developer documentation for NFC classes on the Android developer site.

For example, if you are working at higher level and reading/writing `Ndef` messages:

1. Setup an intent filter (in code or manifest) so you detect `Ndef` or `NDefFormatable` tags. You can get a `Tag` object from the `Intent` passed to you (in `onCreate()` or `onNewIntent()`).

   ```
   Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra( NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG );
   ```
2. From your `Tag` try to get an [`Ndef`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html) tag object from the intent.
3. If successful in getting an `Ndef` object from the tag, then check it is writable, check it has enough space, write to it and then use the `makeReadOnly()` of `Ndef`....
4. If getting an `Ndef` object failed (exception) then you will need to format the Tag first....so...
   get an [`NdefFormattable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NdefFormatable.html) object from the detected `Tag` and write a message to it and protect it, using the `formatReadOnly(NdefMessage firstMessage)`, or just format it and then continue with code to get `Ndef` ...
5. If you can't get an `NdefFormattable` object then something is seriously wrong, as that was what you requested in your filter. Formatting might fail if it is read-only already.

The developer documentation is not too bad, once you get your head around setting the `IntentFilter` by "Tag Technology" (including `NdefFormatable` and `Ndef`) and then getting those objects from the base Tag to do different operations.

Comment: Good enough to be selected the answer? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some NFC Tags can be configured to be read-only.
Some are purchased with your data on them already, and set to read-only.
http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/wireless/nfc/near-field-communications-tags-types.php

Comment: What if i make a NFC tag read only and then some one read that tag and made a duplicate tag.How we can secure these type of tags.So that no one can make duplicate tag.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to ensure that no one else makes a duplicate of your data. For example, if you have a URL as the content of your tag, and someone else reads that data. There is nothing stopping them from encoding a new tag with that same data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write-protect (most) tags, which inhibits others from overwriting your content. If you just want to write a tag, a good android app is [NXP tagwriter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter), which has a variety of encoding options and a write-protect option.

If you want to make it so *only you* have control of your tag's content, try [NFCLabels tag manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartwhere.tagmgr) app. Your tag content is stored in the 'cloud', and you access your tag through your account. So you can write-protect a tag so Joe Schmoe can't blast your content, but you still have freedom to update your tag as needed. It also gives you some basic engagement analytics. Their youtube video shows how it works (see above link.)

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of nfc tags can be protected by locked bits, which you can write an NFC tags with apps like NXP tagwriter, tasklauncher, make sure you have choose **readonly** options for encoding. Beside attention if an tag is read-only, it can not be rewritten again. For apps or nfc tags, go [geenfc](http://www.geenfc.com/en/Download/mobile/) website for details.